# Histogram now showing the correct bin width and height

Tags: histograms

I have multiple datasets that I want to compare in one histogram with values ranging from von 4 to 20.
All of them work correctly except the last one.

```
data = {6, 11, 13, 15, 15}

Histogram[data, 20, "Count"]
```

[image]

I would like the bars to have a width of 1 and the number of possible bars go up to 20 like in this example:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please read the documentation for [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) where you can find details about width specification. Example: ``Histogram[data, {0.5, 20.5, 1}, "Count"]``

Comment: If you are comparing histograms with samples of different sizes, you want to use the "PDF" option (which makes the total area under the bars identical among datasets) rather than the "Count" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Histogram[data, {5, 20, 1}]
```

[image]